# ¿Como Importar un EXCEL a MYSQL usando Codeigniter ? Tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, excel

hace poco pregunte sobre este tema en esta misma web, y ya que he logrado importar los datos de manera correcta, y luego de casi una semana buscando en Internet, decidí que seria bueno publicar una quia sobre ello, ya que la mayor parte de información al respecto esta en ingles, estoy seguro que a mas de alguna persona le va a servir. Debo decir que no soy un experto programando, y que hace poco comencé con codeigniter(la comunidad me ha ayudado mucho), por lo que si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia, es bienvenida.

Lo primero es nuestra base de datos, en este caso, yo tengo una tabla llamada horarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente es nuestro archivo EXCEL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizaremos una librería llama Spout,la pueden descargar de forma gratuita en el siguiente enlace: [Spout](http://opensource.box.com/spout/) una vez lo hayan descargado, lo descomprimen en la carpeta third_party de su proyecto

En este caso solo utilizaremos un controlador llamado cHorarios:

```
 require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';

 use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;  
 use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

  //Con las lineas anteriores cargamos la librería

 class cHorarios extends  CI_Controller{

  function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();

   //esto es de mi proyecto, no lo consideren

    $this->load->model('mLogin');
     $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('mHorarios');

 }

 public function index(){


        //aquí solo estoy cargando el diseño no lo tomen en consideración
        $this->load->view('layouts/header.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/menu.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer.php');

}

 public function guardar_horario(){


 if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {


  $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


   if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
       && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

    // Nombre Temporal del Archivo
    $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    //Lee el Archivo usando ReaderFactory
    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

    //Esta linea mantiene el formato de nuestras horas y fechas
    //Sin esta linea Spout convierte la hora y fecha a su propio formato
    //predefinido como DataTime

    $reader->setShouldFormatDates(true);

    // Abrimos el archivo
    $reader->open($inputFileName);
    $count = 1;

    //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo
    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {

        // Numero de filas en el documento EXCEL
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

            // Lee los Datos despues del encabezado
            // El encabezado se encuentra en la primera fila
         if($count > 1) {


            $data = array(

              //rut_usu, fecha_ini, y fecha_ter son imputs del formulario
              //no se encuentran en el archivo EXCEL
              //los estoy capturando por POST

              'rut_usu' => $this->input->post('rut_usu'),
              'hrs_ini' => $row[0],
              'hrs_ter' => $row[1],
              'lunes' => $row[2],
              'martes' => $row[3],
              'miercoles' => $row[4],
              'jueves' => $row[5],
              'viernes' => $row[6],
              'sabado' => $row[7],
              'fecha_ini' => $this->input->post('fecha_ini'),
              'fecha_ter' => $this->input->post('fecha_ter')

           ); 


          $this->db->insert('horario',$data);

          } 
            $count++;
         }
     }

     // cerramos el archivo EXCEL
      $reader->close();

   } else {

    echo "Seleccione un tipo de Archivo Valido";
   }

 } else {

 echo "Seleccione un Archivo EXCEL";

  }


 }


}
```

Luego en la vista necesitamos los inputs correspondientes, hice una vista para el tutorial, tal vez falte un div, pero lo importante es la linea del formulario, al presionar el boton se guardaran los datos escritos en los inputs y los datos del archivo Excel. Espero les sirva, es mi pequeño aporte a la comunidad, ya que no tengo tantos conocimientos. Me despido.

```
<html lang="es">

<head>

 <title>Titulo de la web</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

 <header>
   <h1>Mi sitio web</h1>
   <p>Mi sitio web creado en html5</p>
 </header>

<section>

 //abrimos el fromulario y llamamos a la función del controlador
 <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cHorarios/guardar_horario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  //los imputs

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sede</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rut_usu" 
          name="rut_usu">   
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sede</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_ini" name="fecha_ini">   
    </div>
  </div>


   <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sede</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_ter" name="fecha_ter">   
   </div>
   </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Seleccione un xlxs</label>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xlsx" class="form-control" > 
      </div>
     </div>


      <div class="col-md-3" style="top:25px; left: 30px;" >
                <div class="form-group">

                    <button type="submit" id="Ingresar" name="Ingresar" class="btn bg-aqua">Guardar</button>
                     <button name="cancelar" id="cancelar" class="btn bg-red" style="width:80px;">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

  </form>

</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [No reconoce las dos primeras columnas(importar EXCEL a DB)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103117/no-reconoce-las-dos-primeras-columnasimportar-excel-a-db)

Comment: Deberías publicar esto como respuesta a tu pregunta original, en lugar de crear una nueva. Es mejor poner esto como respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103117/no-reconoce-las-dos-primeras-columnasimportar-excel-a-db y eliminar esta. En todo caso hacer también alguna modificación a la pregunta original para que sea más canónica

Comment: Decidí borrar el otro post, ya que aquí queda más claro, y no me habían logrado dar una respuesta acertada antes.

Comment: Buenas tardes, como podria hacer para que acepte las extenciones (.XLS , CSV) ? ya que ahora me aceptando solo .XLSX